# How to post Nested Data in swift?

Tags: swift, httprequest, codable

User Struct:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let userId: Int?
    let userName: String?
    let userDocument: [UserDocument]?
}
```

UserDocument Struct:

```
struct UserDocument: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let userDocumentId: Int?
    let userId: Int?
    let documentId: Int?
    let document: Document?
}
```

Document Struct:

```
struct Document: Codable {
    let documentId: Int
    let ownerId: Int?
    let secureName: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let fileExtension: String?
    let fileSize: Int64?
    let url: String?
}
```

And This is Request Body (I'm stuck here):

```
let body: [String: Any?] = ["userId": 0, "userName": "name", "userDcuments": ?....]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using **`Codable`**, you can simply encode your `User` instance using `JSONEncoder's` **`encode(_:)`** method.

```
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) //user is the instance of User
```

Now use this `data` as `httpBody` of `URLRequest`, i.e.

```
if let url = URL(string: "YOUR_URL") {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = data //here...
    //rest of the request configurations..
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Assuming the `User` object is like,

```
let doc = Document(documentId: 0, ownerId: 0, secureName: "", title: "", description: "", fileExtension: "", fileSize: 200, url: "String?")
let userDoc = UserDocument(userDocumentId: 0, userId: 0, documentId: 0, document: doc)
var user = User(userId: 0, userName: "name", userDocument: [userDoc])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this part is okey. I apologize for not adding. I couldn't write body

Comment: @Robert What issue are you facing then?

Comment: I have no problem adding normal struct to body but when I try to nested object the post operation fails. I think I spelled body wrong. How can I write this example body?

Comment: @Robert Why are you even creating the body manually when you have a `User` instance? You can use it directly like I described above.

Comment: @PGDev Maybe add an example with creating a user instance and then encoding it with `.encode(user)` (I know it should be obvious).

Comment: @pawello2222 You must be having that already right if you've created models for it?

Comment: Because I don't need to post some variables.

Comment: I will try to post object with optioanal value. Thank you for your help